# How to measure the duration of a MongoDB aggregation request?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, duration

I want to measure the duration of a MongoDB aggregation request.
I have the following request:
`db.structureone.aggregate( [ { $match: { "keywords": "entrepreneuse" } }])`

Thank you!

Comment: You can generate a query plan with "executionStats" verbosity using the `explain()` method. Look for the `explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis` field in the generated plan.

Comment: The easiest is to set the profiling level : db.setProfilingLevel(0, { slowms: 20, sampleRate: 0.42 })  , at level 0 , but 20ms threshold you will see the query and execution time in the logs when it takes more then 20 ms